# Warn message while executing aapt command

Tags: android, aapt

We are using aapt2 dump command to extract the information from the apk file (`https://developer.android.com/tools/aapt2#:~:text=dump%20is%20used%20for%20printing%20information%20about%20the%20APK%20you%20generated%20using%20the%20link%20command`)

When executing any of the dump commands (badging, packagename, or xmlstrings) using the aapt2 tool, we encounter a "warn" message.

```
aapt2.exe dump packagename weixin_2023482648690_t4mmo.apk

warn: resource com.tencent.mm:raw/aa_entrance_icon for config '' is a file reference to 'res/raw/aa_entrance_icon.svg' but no such path exists. warn: resource com.tencent.mm:raw/aa_paylist_collapse for config '' is a file reference to 'res/raw/aa_paylist_collapse.svg' but no such path exists.
```

(The full warning message is attached in the file)

Despite the warning message, the app details are successfully extracted, and the app can be installed on the device using the package installer without any issues. Upon investigation, it appears that these warning messages may be related to missing or misconfigured resources, or unused resources within the APK.

We would like to seek clarification on the following points:

1. What are the possible causes of the warning messages generated by aapt2?
2. Is it safe to ignore these warning messages? Are they considered non-critical warnings?
3. What potential issues might arise when installing apps that generate such warning messages?

The documentation attached above explains error messages from AAPT but does not cover warning messages. Could someone provide guidance on this matter?